# LDAPS not working in Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu

Tags: ldap, samba

I'm running Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu on Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm unable to get LDAPS (port 636) to work at all.

Samba is running as  an Active Directory Domain Controller, and other AD DC fncitonality seems to be fine.

This used to work, but now there's nothing listening on that port.  I'm not sure what I did to break it, but it stopped working after I updated my server with a trusted certificate.

Here's what I have for /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
# Global parameters
[global]
workgroup = AD
realm = AD.<redacted>.COM
netbios name = SAMBADC
server role = active directory domain controller
dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8
idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
tls enabled  = yes
tls keyfile  = tls/ad.<redacted>.com.key
tls certfile = tls/c7535fc6c5e8e557.crt
tls cafile   = tls/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
ldap server require strong auth = allow_sasl_over_tls

[netlogon]
path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/ad.<redacted>.com/scripts
read only = No

[sysvol]
path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
read only = No
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
nitsadmin@sambadc:/etc/samba$ telnet localhost 636
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Trying ::1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Cannot assign requested address
```

Anyone have any idea why this might not work?  Any idea what `Cannot assign requested address` means?

Comment: Where is your port configuration in the `.conf` file?  What about `iptables` or `firewalld` could you show up the open ports?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide a log file which is specified in your `smb.conf` parameter `log file =` while you start the samba service?

There could be something wrong with your certificates.
One thing you could try is to switch to [autogenerated self-signed certificate](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configuring_LDAP_over_SSL_(LDAPS)_on_a_Samba_AD_DC#Using_the_Samba_autogenerated_self-signed_certificate_.28default.29) and see if it solves the issue. If it does - you have to fix your certificates.

To do this, remove all certificates from tls folder and reconfigure `smb.conf`:

```
tls enabled  = yes
tls keyfile  = tls/key.pem
tls certfile = tls/cert.pem
tls cafile   = tls/ca.pem
```

Then restart samba service and see if it helps.